# setExtremes Event not working post setExtremes method call

Tags: highcharts

I am getting an issue where in setExtremes Event stops firing post setExtremes method is called manually by the user. Please find the link for the problem in JS Fiddle.

```
   <code>http://jsfiddle.net/j7n2msj8/1/</code>
```

Steps to reproduce : 
1. Zoom on the chart.(Working), series is getting updated.
2. Click on show Issue button
3. Try to zoom on the chart(Not working),series is not getting changed.

Please provide the solution for the scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the master branch highstock from http://github.highcharts.com/highstock.js